# CSS: bottom margin of H2 directly after H1

Tags: css, header, margin

I'm looking for a way to give H1 more margin-bottom (or H2 more margin-top) in case h1 and h2 directly follow each other. So in case #1 the normal margins should apply but in case #2 I like to change the margins a bit (to give more "air" between H1 and H2). Tried using 
h1 h2 {margin...} and h1>h2 {margin...} but so far no success.

Case #1

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<p>text</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

Case #2

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
h1 + h2 {
  margin: whatever;
}
```

The + selector is the adjacent selector. It will only affect elements that are adjacent to the preceding element.

Comment: thanks! searched the web really several times but didn't found this. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
h1+h2{
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

It uses the adjacent selector. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ for browser compatibility information.​